# Does JBPM require specific database?

Tags: database, hibernate, jbpm

I am trying to integrate JBPM with different databases ,so I wanted to ask:

- Does JBPM requires any specific Database ?
- How to maintain database in JBPM ?
- For Example if we need to execute delete statement, where do we set it? In JBPM or in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

JBPM comes configured with H2 Database by default, you can change through

1. persistence.xml the default dialect

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
   ```

2. configure DS on standalone.xml

   ```
   <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS</jta-data-source>
   ```

When you start your JBoss instance, it should refresh your database ddl's.

Answer (score 0):

JBPM use with default a inmemory H2 Database.
But you can configure it to make use of other relational database systems. I was able to use Postgres and MS SQL so far.

Please find further instructions about DB config with in the offical docs: https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.3.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_using_a_different_database